# how to display terminal port in linux

Tags: linux

what I am trying to do it show what terminal port im useing when I am currently logged in to my linux server. If anyone could offer some help I would be very greatfull!!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure if you are asking for TCP port or terminal session. This answer applys to the latter -

From the terminal you are logged in to, try the `who` command, e.g:

```
myname@servername:~$ who
somelocaluser   tty7         2014-03-06 14:11
myname  pts/0        2014-04-08 17:16 (192.168.11.8)
```

Or `tty`:

```
myname@servername:~$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```